# Reading row and column index values from GRIB file via netcdf

Tags: netcdf, grib, netcdf-java

Recently I have been working on netcdf files and I am using [this](https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf-java) library. I am able to open and read the data like this:

```
NetcdfFile ncfile = NetcdfFile.open(inputPath);
```

I am able to list variables and get desired variable inside the data:

```
List<Variable> variables = ncfile.getVariables();
Variable tcc = ncFile.findVariable("tcc_0");
```

I am able to get rank and shape of variable too, and I can get data of the table by this:

```
int[] readOrigin = new int[2];
int[] readShape = new int[2]; 

readOrigin[0] = desiredRow;
readOrigin[1] = 0;

readShape[0] = 1;
readShape[1] = numberOfColumns;

Array arr = tcc.read(readOrigin, readShape);
```

This code gets all the values of 'desiredRow'th row and I can iterate over `arr` and find each specific value for each column.

However, I want to get all the values for columns and row indexes. When I want to achieve table's [0][0] value, I can achieve that. By I am not able to achieve all the row and column index values. I need to get 32.035, 32.08, ... for the row index values and same for the columns.

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found a way to get them. They are called root group and has 1 dimensional data inside it which is exactly what I needed.

```
Variable rootGroupLatitudeVar = ncFile.getRootGroup().findVariableLocal("latitude");
Array latitudeArr = rootGroupLatitudeVar.read();
int latitudeArrSize = rootGroupLatitudeVar.getShape(0);

..iteration
```